# Deleting an array by the number in it, C

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main() //8th task
{
    int longNum, shortNum, tempNum[5], i;
    printf("Please enter 2 numbers (5 digits and 1 digit, ex: 12345 and 5)\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &longNum, &shortNum);
    for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (longNum % 10 != shortNum)
        {
            tempNum[i] = longNum % 10;
            longNum /= 10;
        }
        else tempNum[i] = ; // Delete the digit that == shortNum.
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", tempNum[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

This program check if longNum has shortNum in it and suppose to remove the number (and his array slot) from longNum.
I've tried couple of things to make it work with no success.
I'd like to know what is the best way to do it (im not sure what the 'else' should be).

Comment: Assuming this is a programming assignment, do you have to use integer operations but not a string matching algorithm perhaps? With string matching, it becomes a lot simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to skip all `shortNum` digits in the parsing loop. One more variable is needed to track number of deleted digits:

```
int n = 5;
for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
{
    int tmp = longNum % 10;
    longNum /= 10;

    if (tmp != shortNum)
        tempNum[--n] = tmp; 
}

// here n is number of deleted digits
for (i = n; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%d", tempNum[i]);
}
```

So, actually elements are not deleted from array. They are not written to that array. It is also possible to reverse elements order, so the first array element will be meaningful. Now if some element is skipped the first element of `tempNum` contains junk.

Comment: Can you go into details about this part of the code : `if (tmp != shortNum)
        tempNum[--n] = tmp;` i dont understand what it does exactly.

Comment: @Morta1 If the digit under test (`tmp`) is not equal to `shortNum` it should be saved, so decrease counter `n` by `1` and use the resulting value of `n` as index for `tempNum` to save the digit.

Answer (score 1):

you need to skip the value that you don't want, and not insert it at all to the array.

```
int len = 0;
for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (longNum % 10 != shortNum)
    {            
        tempNum[len] = longNum % 10;            
        len++;
    }        
    longNum /= 10;
}
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    printf("%d", tempNum[i]);
}
```

Comment: It would be perfecrt if the print loop iterated in reverse order: `for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)` (assuming that `i` is of signed type!). In that case digits would be printed in the order of input.

Answer (score -1):

`else tempNum[i] = ;` this part is very wrong. You have to assing something like `else tempNum[i] = 0;`. And you can't actually delete anything from these arrays - they are not dynamic. I suggest you read up on dynamic arrays.

Comment: It doesn't, thats what i just dont know what to put there to make it work.

Comment: **this part is very wrong, like ultra wrong**, there is no such thing called ultra wrong, it is a syntax error and OP is asking what to replace there, please suggest that

Comment: dynamic arrays is your friend. you can only try tempNum[i] = 0, but that is not actually deleting it.

Comment: Despite your revision this is still a low-quality answer.  Why not show the OP how they could use  dynamic arrays to solve their problem?